# How to object-orient-design a hiearchy of objects with "static" methods

Tags: java, oop

Say, i want to create a `Validator` `interface` or `abstract class` -> the idea is that each class that `implements` or `extends` from this `Validator` should implement a method called `validate(String input)`

The idea is that i want to just call `LastNameValidator.validate("McDonalds")` such that i don't have to create an instance of the validator.

However, i can't make the method `validate(String input)` `static` in either case of an `interface` `Validator` nor `abstract class` `Validator`. (prolly cus static methods are already created at class loading?)

I also don't care to make instances using `Singleton` or `Factory` that `implement` or `extends` `Validator`, because i don't see the need to create such instance just to call static methods

What is the OOP/Java way to do such a thing?

================================================================================
Clarification:

i want to do `public static abstract void validate(String input)` in the `Validator` abstract class

OR

i want to do `public static void validate(String input)` in the `Validator` interface

but of course, these are syntactically invalid. what is the valid way to not create an instance of Validator but have these static methods be "overriden" (or alternatively, convince me that i MUST HAVE an instance of such a class to call a mere `static` method?)

Comment: `"...such that i don't have to create an instance of the validator."` -- This smells of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that you may be barking up the wrong tree completely to solve this problem. Why do you feel that you shouldn't be making Validator instances?

Comment: with the keyword static, you can call its method without creating an instance of it. You said you want your actual class implement or extends that class. Does your actual class also required be static class?

Comment: avoid using static classes, it is not very good habit in java programming i must say, according to your question you will have problems with compilation of that code

Comment: @SCV: What do you mean? Java doesn't even have static stand-alone classes.

Comment: static methods are not polymorphic, so they don't lend themselves to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't care if the class is static or anonymous. i want to not bother with an instance of Validator when i don't need to create one (i guess in the back of my mind i'm thinking this creates extra data/implications when there is no need for one)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, there should not be "static class". I made a typo in words. I think GriffeyDog said what I want to say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using static methods is surely not "very" object-oriented. That's why Java won't even compile a source file where both `static` and `abstract` modifiers are attached to a certain method. So none of the two options you posted in the end of your question will work. (interface methods are abstract by default, even if you don't explicitly add the modifier).

If you don't want to use singletons (not sure why), you can apply a classic factory pattern, maybe combined with defining an enumeration containing all possible validator types. Here's a random example:

**Enum:**

```
public enum ValidatorType{
    AGE,LAST_NAME;
}
```

**Factory class**

```
public class ValidatorFactory{
    public static Validator getValidator(ValidatorType type){
        if(ValidatorType.AGE.equals(type)){
            return new AgeValidator(); //won't post the AgeValidator definition here
        }
        if(ValidatorType.LAST_NAME.equals(type)){
            return new LastNameValidator(); //won't post the LastNameValidator definition here
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Client code**

```
ValidatorFactory.getValidator(ValidatorType.LAST_NAME).validate("Burger King");
```

Comment: sorry - let me clarify. i want to do those two things in the java way. how do i do so?

Comment: @DavidT: by not trying to do this in a static way.

Comment: "_interface methods are static by default_." No they aren't.

Comment: What is the benefit of creating a singleton in this case, where i don't actually need an instance of the class? I was thinking this is more of like a `Utils` class where there are only static methods

Comment: @GriffeyDog: I meant abstract haha. I'm sure you knew what I meant ;)

Comment: @David T. I'm not saying there's any benefit. I'm just saying this is the OOP way. If it doesn't suit you, why don't you try a functional oriented language? Java language creators started from the assumption/generalization that you might need an instance (a state that might be created by previous events) in order to define the behavior of an abstract specification.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan gotcha. sounds like you and the other guy is right. there isn't a OOP solution to this classic problem. Thanks for the insight

Comment: also, sorry about making you write the extra factory code there. when i said i didn't want a singleton, i meant to say it's because i don't want to create instances. but +1 for the code :)

Answer (score 4):

> but of course, these are syntactically invalid. what is the valid way to not create an instance of Validator but have these static methods be "overriden"

This smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that you may be barking up the wrong tree completely to solve this problem.

I feel that the correct solution is to create an instance, perhaps using a factory, but regardless of how you do it, creating an instance.

You state:

> I don't care if the class is static or anonymous. i want to not bother with an instance of Validator when i don't need to create one (i guess in the back of my mind i'm thinking this creates extra data/implications when there is no need for one)

If you have not profiled your code with creating instances, and have not found it to be a memory or speed bottle neck, then this is smells like bad premature optimization. Please understand that most of the cost of coding is in the debugging and maintenance. You are proposing to create code that will be much more difficult to maintain, to ***unit test***, and to enhance. Sorry, but if you're going to make restrictions that go against the philosophy of OOP, you'd better have a strong basis for doing so.

Comment: In fact, what we face here is a classical functional programming problem. Maybe the OP will get happier with the release of JDK 8. Lambdas might look more natural to him.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan: you are probably right. They look quite cool to me, but even then, behind the scenes, I strongly suspect that you are creating instances with your lambdas.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan: nice answer by the way. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you bring up a good point - i don't need to think about pre-optimization. yes. however, i'm still not convinced i NEED an instance of validator, when i can't think of a reason to have one. I just want to use static methods from that class. think `Utils` static methods

Comment: You're definitely creating instances with the lambdas. But I was saying from the code writer's point of view, where lambdas hide this fact pretty well and fit better such mindsets like the OP's.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the answer, i also didn't know what the XY problem is. :) +1